# Im trying to run a program in Visual Studio I keep getting an error message every time I try and debug

Tags: c++, debugging

At first i would get an error message saying the program could not locate the directory and now i am getting an error message that is saying "Unable to start program 'C\Users\myname\source\repos\1-5assignment\x64\debug\1-5 assignment.exe'. This program is blocked by group policy. for more information, contact your system admin

I've tried to look up guides and posts through the web but have come up short so far and i am just confused as to what I should do now.

Comment: try a) moving the exe somewhere else b) renaming it to something not quite so odd (testapp.exe maybe)

Comment: This is likely a sys-admin issue and certainly unrelated to your code or visual studio.  Telling us you searched for answers and came up short may say more about your search fu than the availability of solutions.  It is redundant information unless you say what you tried that did not work.  For example have you tried these solutions: https://www.isunshare.com/blog/this-program-is-blocked-by-group-policy-error-windows-10/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your system admin has [blocked executing arbitrary executables](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-block-exe-files-from-running-using-group-policy-in-windows-11-10). Contact them and explain and they'll either tell you why you cannot execute them, or will add exclusions for you.

You can try building it in a different location than the Users directory incase they have simply blocked all executables in there (ie your user home directory) to stop random stuff running from the default internet downloads directory.